# How do I install commerceguys/addressing and commerceguys/int

Tags: commerce

I am trying to install drupal commerce i have put the files in their proper place (folders etc) but its like i didn tdo anything because it is not working for me. What should i do

[image: Installed Modules]

[image: Error Message]

Answer (score 2):

As per [the project page](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce), "Commerce 2.x should only be installed via Composer", and via the [Drupal commerce documentation site](https://docs.drupalcommerce.org/commerce2/developer-guide/install-update/installation#existing-site):

```sh
cd /path/to/drupal8
composer require "drupal/commerce"
```

Otherwise, if you are using Ludwig, you could try following [the installation instructions for Drupal Commerce with Ludwig](https://www.drupal.org/docs/contributed-modules/ludwig/drupal-commerce-ludwig-installation-guide).